# Using opencv FileStorage native in android

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, native

I am trying to write an android applications witch calculates keypoints and descriptors using opencv and store them. However i am getting troubles with cv:FileStorage. I am actually passing the file path throw native methods. The same path (different file ending) is also used to store another file on the javaside.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_..._CalcFeatures(JNIEnv* env, jobject, jlong addrGray, jstring location){
...
const char *nativeString = env->GetStringUTFChars(location, NULL);
string filepath=string(nativeString);
FileStorage fs(filepath, FileStorage::WRITE);
fs<<"frameCount"<<5;
fs.release();
...
}
```

**LogCat output:**

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x000009f4 (code=19), thread 23789
```

I also tryed to hardcode the path (like „/sdcard/test.xml“ or „/storage/emulated/0/text.xml“). If I am using “test.xml” as filepath, I don’t get any errors, but I am not able to find the file on my phone (HTC One).

Any advices?

Thanks for your time.

**UPDATE:**

this works just fine, so there is a problem with FileStorage. Is there any other way in opencv to parse it to an xml/json format? perhaps with string as result?

```
FILE* file = fopen(nativeString,"w+");
fputs("hello, world\n", file);
fclose(file);
```

Comment: did you acquire write permission for your app ?

Comment: also, don't expect it to generate subdirs magically

Comment: yes, i acquired write permissions. The subdir already exists, java part writes another file in the same dir.

Comment: You might find this usefull: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21922685/1085483

Answer (score 0):

I've asked similar question here: [imread returns empty matrix while ifstream can open and read the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541422/imread-returns-empty-matrix-while-ifstream-can-open-and-read-the-same-file) and I found that even if I can manipulate file from native part, I cant use opencv's FileStorage.

And that's why I'm not able to load matrix,cascade classifier,etc.

I also tried load data from file to memory and create FileStorage from memory, it created for writing, but it does not works (while it works on windows perfectly). I cant access to any node.