# How to read OpenCV Mat Object from file in Android?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, mat, file-storage

I have a Bag Of Words dictionary created on my computer and saved to xml file. I'm creating an app for Android and I need to use it. Unfortunately according to [Andrey Smorodov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679508/using-opencv-filestorage-native-in-android) it turns out that I can't use the OpenCV FileStorage class, for some reason. Do you have any idea what approach should I use? Can you give an example or reference? Also I'm going to use SVM, so will I have problem with svm.load("classifier.xml")? I'm using Android NDK but I don't mind if I should do this in Java.

Comment: `Unfortunately I found out that I can't use the OpenCV FileStorage class, for some reason.` What is that reason?

Comment: svm.load() [should work](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/ml/CvStatModel.html#load(java.lang.String)). what does *not* work here, is opening an arbitrary Filestorage, and reading Mat's from that. (unless you outsource that to jni)

Comment: So you tell me that I can use FileStorage without problem if I use it in my native part?

Comment: haven't tried, but i guess, very much so. themain obstacle (in java) is just, that there are no overloaded operators like '>>' . but no prob in c++ !

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'll try and will write here after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I successfully used FileStorage in the native code. I read my files properly. Don't forget to add the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest. (Like @Ken said)

Answer (score 1):

I was also having trouble with FileStorage in native code.  I was getting a SIGABRT crash with no useful message.  The solution for me was to add READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to the permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml.  Now it works just fine.